# How to fill data horizontally when required condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a data from column A to D, if cell value in D is Completed then respective B value is to be entered in row consecutively. Please help on this.

Comment: Show your code, show expected result and be more specific in your description. Unless you do that, nobody won't be able to help you.

Comment: I have done this by formula

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot [edit it in your post] of example data and expected result please? I will be able to help you then... Thank you.

Comment: Please ensure that your post is complete.  You should have a statement about the goal, what you've tried (including any formulas or code), and list the error/problem you receive (if code, specify which line).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly if your Column D is populated then you want the the contents of Column B in say Column E

If so use the formula IF(D2="","",B2) in Column E

[image: Formula to add to populate data from Column B]